# "caretaker" badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Awarded for going over your old questions (> x months/years) and making edits.

For instance, I asked a question ages ago about implementing RAII behaviour in C# in which I used the example of a logger to explain the question. I stupidly named the question after the logger example, instead of the RAII issue at heart.

I saw the mistake while looking around my old questions today, fixed it, and thought it would be good to incentivise people to de-weed and repaint their old questions occasionally.

Maybe it could be extended to adding comments or voting on answers on really old quesitons, but I guess if there's new activity SO is already good at flagging this for attention. It's tweaking the questions with no more answers, but still regular views, that this badge should be rewarding.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, however I will limit this to one badge only, given after editing old (older than 6 months?) question of yours for the first time. Bronze badge, of course. Plus, if the question is Community Wiki it won't grant the badge.

Answer (score 10):

This is to easy to fake/game. And because badges are to encourage good behaviour it's probably better to award the badge if:

1. You have edited an older question with no or no accepted answers (or even no upvoted answers).
2. After the edit, at least a new answer has been added or an existing answer is edited by the original owner.
3. The new or renewed answer got a couple of upvotes.

That way you encourage people to update their older questions. And you even encourage others to update their answers when appropriate.